# Constantly getting 'cancels Clean Self: Area inaccessible.' messages

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm constantly getting messages such as:
Döbar Olonrerras, Miner cancels Clean Self: Area inaccessible.

in my log and now I've realized it's become a Problem:
[image]

How do I figure out why dwarves are not cleaning themselves (or the fort)? They have 2 wells and a perfectly good river as Water Sources.

Comment: But hey... at least her hair is neatly combed.

Comment: The only *proper* solution to this problem is to drown all your dwarves in magma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dreaded "Urist McDirty cancels clean self:Area inaccessible." message-spam stems from dwarfs trying to clean themselves with soap, typically by trying to clean a missing part of his body.

After realizing the error of their way, they put the soap back on the stockpile, walk away, and go on with their activities, which, incidentally, is clean self, resulting in a message-spam generating loop.

This is a [known bug](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=1023) related to [soap](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Soap) and the only solutions for now are not to create soap or temporarily forbidding all soap bars through the stock menu, so the culprits in question will wash themselves at a well or pool, without trying to use soap, or increasing the soap stock levels in the hospital, moving all the soap over there which disallows it to be used for general cleaning.

Comment: Thanks - that certainly explained it. Though by this point, half of my fortress was covered in all sorts of blood and dying miserable deaths. I let the HFS take care of the rest :p